# How to access hardware using Gamesalad tool?

Tags: android-hardware, hardware, gamesalad

I'm learning on **GameSalad** tool and I'm wondering if I can access the **hardware** using this tool, for example:- can I turn on the flash light in the back of my mobile phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gamesalad is a closed platform. You can do just what the developers implemented.

This platform is for games so I don't think there is any way to control hardware especially the Flashlight.

All actions that could be preformed are suppose to be under Library -> Behaviors, but those are related to the game engine itself (in-app purchase, share with twitter and game flow control).